# Why aren't patterns allowed in "use" bindings?

Tags: f#

According to the [spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597481), a `use` binding requires an identifier (unlike `let`) instead of a pattern. Why is this? Here's an example of a scenario that doesn't work.

```
type Disposable = Resource of IDisposable

let f disposable =
  use (Resource d) = disposable //ERROR: 'use' bindings must be of the form 'use <var> = <expr>'
  ()
```

Comment: Odd, I think you better try and explain what you are doing. This code doesn't make enough sense.

Comment: @vcsjones: As kvb pointed out, the code was incorrect. The odd error message was a red herring. However, my central point is still relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the likely answer is that lots of patterns don't make sense.  For instance, how would you expect the compiler to handle the following code?

```
type DisposablePair = DisposablePair of IDisposable * IDisposable

let f disposablePair =
    use (DisposablePair(x,y)) = disposablePair
    ()
```

Your weird error message is probably due to the fact that even if you were using a `let` binding, you'd need to bind `(Resource d)` rather than `Resource(d)` (the compiler thinks you're declaring a new function).

For what it's worth, I do find the inability to use an underscore pattern to be an annoyance at times (particularly when dealing with `IDisposable` instances that exist only to demarcate scopes, like `System.Transactions.TransactionScope`).  One way to generalize `use` bindings to handle underscores and a few other situations would be to require the right hand side of a `use` binding to be an `IDisposable` but to allow any pattern on the left hand side, so that:

```
use p = v in e
```

would syntactically translate to something like

```
let ((p:System.IDisposable) as d) = v in try e finally d.Dispose()
```

Comment: Oops, sorry for my sloppiness there. The gyst of the question still holds. I like your proposed solution. Frankly, I'd probably be just as happy without `use`. I prefer the syntax and behavior of `using`.

Comment: One answer to your initial question is all identifiers in the pattern must bind to IDisposables. However, I prefer your solution (although I can't think of a use beyond allowing wildcards).